# How do Indian citizens who are Canadian PRs apply for Global entry (instead of NEXUS)?

Tags: indian-citizens, global-entry, nexus, trusted-traveler, canadian-permanent-residents

When I go through the TTP application questionnaire, I select my county of citizenship as India, and choose "I'm a permanent resident of Canada". How do I apply for global entry, instead of NEXUS? I don't get the option to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Canadian Permanent Residents aren't eligible for Global Entry on that basis alone ([chart](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/))

The eligible Global Entry list is as follows :

- U.S. citizens
- U.S. lawful permanent residents
- and select foreign nationals

But you are eligible as an Indian citizen, in which case you must follow the instructions for an Indian citizen, which will include an interview **in person, in India**

Excerpt from the [Indian Nationals](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/international-arrangements/global-entry-indian-citizens) page **make sure to check the link for updates**

> - Apply Online with CBP: Complete a TTP online application and pay the $100 non-refundable application fee.
> - After completion of step ‘1’ applicants need to submit the requisite information, along with the applicable fee of ₹500, in the
>   Passport Seva Portal, [www.passportindia.gov.in](http://www.passportindia.gov.in) for their background
>   check in India. In addition to this, all Indian applicants must
>   schedule an in-person interview at the respective Passport Seva
>   Kendra/Passport Seva Laghu Kendra (PSK/PSLK) office as per their
>   residential jurisdiction in India (as per the address furnished
>   online). During the interview, Indian citizens will have their
>   fingerprints and photo captured and complete other formalities. A
>   visit to the PSK/PSLK is based on prior appointment only.
> - If the applicant is not presently living in India, it is recommended that they apply for Global Entry prior to their next trip
>   to India so that the appointment at the PSK/PSLK office can be
>   completed during their visit.
> - Schedule an Interview in the U.S.: Once your application is reviewed, you will receive a message in your TTP account instructing
>   you to schedule an interview at one of the Global Entry Enrollment
>   Centers.  If you are unable to schedule an in-person interview, you
>   may opt to use the Enrollment On Arrival (EoA) option that is
>   immediately available while entering the U.S. from an international
>   country.  No appointment is required for the EoA process. Additional
>   information regarding EoA is available on the Enrollment on Arrival
>   website.
> - Interview Determines Your Eligibility: A U.S. Customs Border Protection officer will ask you questions, take your photo, and
>   collect your fingerprints.
> - Provide Identification: Bring your valid passport(s) and one other form of identification, such as a driver's license or ID card to the
>   interview. If you are a lawful permanent resident, you must present
>   your permanent resident card.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that I’m eligible for global entry as an Indian citizen. The problem is this - I have Canadian permanent residency as well. So the initial questionnaire (the one that determines your eligiblity for all trusted traveler programs) asks me what country I’m a citizen of, to which I answer “India”. The next question asks me to choose from the following.

1. I’m a Lawful permanent resident of the US
2. I’m a permanent resident of Canada
3. I’m a permanent resident of Mexico
4. None of the above

Comment: The moment I choose option 2, I get only two options to choose from: NEXUS and SENTRI. If I choose option 4 (which would be inaccurate), I get “Global Entry” as an option in addition to NEXUS and SENTRI. So in short, I don’t get the global entry option if I’m a Canadian permanent resident, even if I’m an Indian citizen.

Comment: @surcasm Did you find the answer to this question? I am also stuck in the same boat, and the website is not showing me Global Entry as an option.